# Can't call phone in background

Tags: java, android, kotlin, call, android-workmanager

I get "calling..." in logs, but it doesn't call. I'm using WorkManager. I also tried AlarmManager, Service, BroadcastReceiver, but it didn't work.

```
  public void doAction(){
    context = getApplicationContext();
    long phone = Long.parseLong(Preferences.getLastNum(context));
    String message = Preferences.getLastMessage(context);
    String action = Preferences.getAction(context);
    Log.i(TAG, action);
    if(action != null) {
        if (action.equals("call")) {
            Log.i(TAG, "calling...");
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
            context.startActivity(i);
        } else if (action.equals("sms")){
            Log.i(TAG, "sending...");
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(phone), null, message, null, null);
        }
    } else{
        Log.i(TAG, "ERROR: action = null");
      }
       Preferences.clearPreferences(context, "0");
   }
```

Comment: You cannot start an activity from the background on modern versions of Android.

Comment: And what's solution?

Comment: can I call phone without Intent?

Comment: "can I call phone without Intent?" -- an ordinary app cannot. "And what's solution?" -- raise a `Notification` and, if the user clicks on it, start the call.

Comment: my app idea is calling phone after certain time set user. Without additional click

Comment: I think that you should have some error in the logs. Please check.